# Quickbooks desktop integration for MAC

Tags: macos, sdk, quickbooks

I have developed a Quickbooks integration for Windows using Visual Studio 2010 and qbsdk13. I would like to do the same thing on a MAC PC. Quickbooks Desktop is available for MAC. Researching the web I deduced that the qbsdk is not supported on MAC. What may I do to achieve a similar integration on MAC? What softwares might help me achieve this ? Can anyone help me regarding this ?

Comment: What have you looked at so far? If you show you've already tried to investigate you are more likely to get a good answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is what i have from Intuit developer forum 
https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1364754

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickBooks for Mac does not support any sort of integration.

> What may I do to achieve a similar integration on MAC?

You can't.

> What softwares might help me achieve this ?

There are none.